# I'm wondering if ngTemplateOutletInjector can be used to make NgModel work in an embedded template wrapped by a form: what does NgModel require?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngmodel

As of angular 14 the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive has a new parameter: `ngTemplateOutletInjector`, which according to the angular docs, defines an "injector to be used within the embedded view."

Since hierarchical injection was the roadblock to wrapping template outlets in forms like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tRef"></ng-container>
</form>
```

... it seems like this might be overcome by using a custom injector to provide whatever an `NgModel` instance needs to integrate with the form.  But, if possible, you would need to know exactly what to provide in said injector.

These are the NgModel dependencies:

```
  @Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer,
  @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: (Validator|ValidatorFn)[],
  @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators:
      (AsyncValidator|AsyncValidatorFn)[],
  @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[],
  @Optional() @Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) private _changeDetectorRef?: ChangeDetectorRef|null)
```

Can anyone shed light on what would be required here?

Comment: Is that what you are trying to achieve? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-do7k5t?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @MehyarSawas It is in a similar vein of thought, but this one is incomplete.  If you inspect the form, you can see that it is pristine after modifying the value.  This is because the NgModel instance is not truly bound to the form, because of hierarchical injection (it cannot access the form via DI).

It's all good though I found my answer which I'm about to post :)

Comment: Still you did not share the whole picture of your issue, your question and answer are missing more details about the use case for your idea.

Comment: I don't know how to say it more succinctly.  NgModel works with forms by dependency injection.  Putting it into a an embedded template that does not contain the form complicates this as it's an entirely different context with a different injector available to the directive.  That is my starting point.  The post is about using ngTemplateOutletInjector to specify the injector.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It looks for me like your code example is missing the use case. You are explaining the first half of the story by telling about the environment (where the ngModel will be used), but the other half about how you are using the ngModel ist not clear. There are many ways to do that, so tell us about your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `NgForm` instance must be provided as its base type, `ControlContainer` to be accessible to an `NgModel` instance.

In the code I am currently working on, this worked (implementation may vary):

```
let injector = Injector.create({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: () => component.form
    }
  ]      
});
```